# How to create server for persistent stream (aka pubsub) in Golang GRPC

Tags: go, streaming, grpc

I am building service that needs to send events to all subscribed consumers in Pub/Sub manner eg. send one event to **all currently connected clients**.

I am using Protobuf for that with the following proto definition:

```
service EventsService {
  rpc ListenForEvents (AgentProcess) returns (stream Event) {}
}
```

Both server & client are written in Go.

My problem is that when client initiates connection then the stream it is not long-lived, eg. when server returns from `ListenForEvents` method:

```golang
func (e EventsService) ListenForEvents(process *pb.AgentProcess, listener pb.EventsService_ListenForEventsServer) error {
    //persist listener here so it can be used later when backend needs to send some messages to client

    return nil
}
```

then the client almost instantly gets `EOF` error which means that server probably closed connection.

What do I do so that the client is subscribed for a long time to the server? **The main problem** is that I might not have anything to send to the client when it calls `ListenForEvents` method on the server, this is why I want this stream **to be long lived** to be able to send messages later.

Comment: You might want to use a real message queue, for example [NATS](https://nats-io.github.io/docs/) and [subjects](https://nats-io.github.io/docs/developer/concepts/subjects.html)

Comment: Thank @MarkusWMahlberg. I agree that it would be better to use something more sophisticated but I still want to know do and don't of GRPC.

Answer (score 2):

The stream terminates when you return from the server function. Instead, you should receive events somehow, and send them to the client without returning from your server. There are probably many ways you can do this. Below is the sketch of one way of doing it.

This relies on the server connection running on a separate goroutine. There is a Broadcast() function that will send messages to all connected clients. It looks like this:

```
var allRegisteredClients map[*pb.AgentProcess]chan Message
var clientsLock sync.RWMutex{}

func Broadcast(msg Message) {
  clientsLock.RLock()
  for _,x:=range allRegisteredClients {
      x<-msg
  }
  clientsLock.RUnlock()
}
```

Then, your clients have to register themselves, and process messages:

```
func (e EventsService) ListenForEvents(process *pb.AgentProcess, listener pb.EventsService_ListenForEventsServer) error {
   clientsLock.Lock()
   ch:=make(chan Message)
   allRegisteredClients[process]=ch
   clientsLock.Unlock()

   for msg:=range ch {
       // send message
       // Deal with errors
       // Deal with client terminations
   }
   clientsLock.Lock()
   delete(allRegisteredClients,process)
   clientsLock.Unlock()
}
```

As I said, this is only a sketch of the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I did modify it a bit :) See my response.

Comment: Yours is racy. Also, to do that, you need to pass in a pointer receiver for EventsService.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to nail it down.

Basically I never return from method `ListenForEvents`.
It creates channel, persists in global-like map of subscribed clients and keeps reading from that channel indefinitely.

The whole implementation of server logic:

```golang
func (e EventsService) ListenForEvents(process *pb.AgentProcess, listener pb.EventsService_ListenForEventsServer) error {
    chans, exists := e.listeners[process.Hostname]

    chanForThisClient := make(chan *pb.Event)

    if !exists {
        e.listeners[process.Hostname] = []chan *pb.Event{chanForThisClient}
    } else {
        e.listeners[process.Hostname] = append(chans, chanForThisClient)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case <-listener.Context().Done():
            return nil
        case res := <-chanForThisClient:
            _ = listener.Send(res)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Did this work out? how performant was this? didnt the connection break- since the connection can wait for a long time

Comment: I need to reflect on this code to see if locks are not needed. Anyhow, it helped me constructing my code. 
In my solution, I use longer deadlines and reconnection on the client side, to avoid other problems of indefinite calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide keepalive settings for grpc client and server

- See details here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md
- Examples https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/keepalive